# Google Pie Chart not showing slice percentage for some slices

Tags: google-visualization

Hi i am new to google charts. I have created one pie chart that is not showing the slice percentage for some slices and it shown for some other slices which have the same value. for better understanding see below screenshot two 6.1% shown in slice itself but another one 6.1% not shown as i showed in tooltips why this strange behavior .And one more issue i have other option in my data itself. So can we change the sliceVisibilityThreshold option text "other" to some other like combined like that.

[image]

Comment: although it doesn't make sense, the slice text isn't shown because there isn't enough room, making chart bigger should fix -- to change "other" label, set option for `pieResidueSliceLabel`